# Python - convert dictionary key from Unicode to string

Tags: python

The output of the following code is "unicode". How can I convert the key inside the dictionary to string?

```
for k in {'HTTP_REFERER':'http://localhost'}.keys():
    print "type---> :%s" % type(k)
```

Comment: You could use the `encode` method. But first be sure that's what you want - `unicode` objects are like `str` objects in most respects, and easier to work with at the character level.

Comment: On a side note: using `keys()` could add an extra overhead. You can drop it.

Comment: This only makes sense in python2 with `unicode_listerals` future import, if so you need to use `b'HTTP_REFERER'` to get a `str`